# Steeltoe Postgres connector on CloudFoundry .NET 5.0

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, .net-5, steeltoe

I am using Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.Connector.EFCore with Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL. I want to migrate the application to .NET 5.0. After updating Npgsql to 5.0.2 I am getting the error 'Unable to find DbContextOptionsBuilder, are you missing a PostgreSql EntityFramework Core assembly?' when adding DBContext.

I tried to look at the available versions of Steeltoe, but the highest NuGet I see is 2.5.2, which gives me this error as well as the older I had (2.4.4).

Is there any version combination of those libraries that works?

Comment: Please check [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The name of that Steeltoe package changed in 3.0](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/welcome/whats-new.html#service-connectors), you'll be needing `Steeltoe.Connector.EFCore` going forward.

The name of that particular type inside `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` changed in 5.0, so that's what is preventing Steeltoe from finding it. The fix has also been applied to the 2.x branch and is included in version 2.5.3.

Check the Steeltoe Samples repo for both [2.x](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/2.x/Connectors/src/AspDotNetCore/PostgreEFCore) and [3.x](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/main/Connectors/src/PostgreEFCore) versions

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. There is just one catch: The version 3.0.2 of Steeltoe.Connector.EFCore seems to have a bug - it behaves as if I never called "AddCloudFoundryConfiguration", ignores the bound db service and tries to connect to a database called '(null)' on localhost:<default_port>. But the version 2.5.3 works fine.

Comment: For version 3.0, the Cloud Foundry specific parts of Connectors were moved to a separate package, so when you upgrade you need to add a reference to `Steeltoe.Connector.CloudFoundry`